# Deleting first instance of date in dataframe value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Publication Date        Date              Value
2018-01-01              2018-01-01        2
2018-01-01              2018-01-02        13
2018-01-01              2018-01-03        14
2018-01-01              2018-01-04        12
2018-01-02              2018-01-02        1.5
2018-01-02              2018-01-03        14
2018-01-02              2018-01-04        15
2018-01-02              2018-01-05        15.5
2018-01-03              2018-01-03        1.8
2018-01-03              2018-01-04        13
2018-01-03              2018-01-05        17
2018-01-03              2018-01-06        15
.
.
```

I want to delete every 1st row of the data where the `Publication Date` changes because there are very small values on each iteration. The output would look like:

```
Publication Date        Date              Value
2018-01-01              2018-01-02        13
2018-01-01              2018-01-03        14
2018-01-01              2018-01-04        12
2018-01-02              2018-01-03        14
2018-01-02              2018-01-04        15
2018-01-02              2018-01-05        15.5
2018-01-03              2018-01-04        13
2018-01-03              2018-01-05        17
2018-01-03              2018-01-06        15
.
.
```

The data is basically in this format but includes extra columns not shown (ie: the `Date` switches by Date+1 for every `Publication Date`).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
res = df[df.duplicated(subset=['PublicationDate'])]
```

Or, more generalizable, using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) or [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) with `groupby`:

```
res = df[df.groupby('PublicationDate').cumcount() > 0]

res = df.groupby('PublicationDate').apply(lambda x: x.tail(len(x)-1))\
        .reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

  PublicationDate        Date  Value
0      2018-01-01  2018-01-02   13.0
1      2018-01-01  2018-01-03   14.0
2      2018-01-01  2018-01-04   12.0
3      2018-01-02  2018-01-03   14.0
4      2018-01-02  2018-01-04   15.0
5      2018-01-02  2018-01-05   15.5
6      2018-01-03  2018-01-04   13.0
7      2018-01-03  2018-01-05   17.0
8      2018-01-03  2018-01-06   15.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use boolean indexing with shift

```
df[df['Publication Date'] == df['Publication Date'].shift()]


    Publication Date    Date    Value
1   2018-01-01  2018-01-02  13.0
2   2018-01-01  2018-01-03  14.0
3   2018-01-01  2018-01-04  12.0
5   2018-01-02  2018-01-03  14.0
6   2018-01-02  2018-01-04  15.0
7   2018-01-02  2018-01-05  15.5
9   2018-01-03  2018-01-04  13.0
10  2018-01-03  2018-01-05  17.0
11  2018-01-03  2018-01-06  15.0
```